# startsWith Function that returns a string instead of a Boolean?

Tags: r, string, startswith

I was working with the `startsWith` function. I was wondering how I could get it to return the actual string name instead of the boolean. I'm open to using other functions as well.

```
startsWith(c("sad_game", "angry_mad", "happy_name"), "happy")
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `startsWith`, use `grep` to return the value on the fly with `^` to specify the start of the string (EDIT - Based on @Ben Bolker comments)

```
grep("^happy", c("sad_game", "angry_mad", "happy_name"), value = TRUE)
[1] "happy_name"
```

---

`startsWith` returns a logical vector.  We need to take the logical vector as index for subsetting the original vector

```
c("sad_game", "angry_mad", "happy_name")[startsWith(c("sad_game", 
      "angry_mad", "happy_name"), "happy")]
```

Note that in the above, we have to type the original vector two times.  Better option would be to create an object and reuse it

```
v1 <- c("sad_game", "angry_mad", "happy_name")
v1[starts_with(v1, "happy")]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your helpful response. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use `str_subset` from `stringr`

```
x <- c("sad_game", "angry_mad", "happy_name")
stringr::str_subset(x, '^happy')
#[1] "happy_name"
```

which is based on `stringi::stri_subset_regex`

```
stringi::stri_subset_regex(x, '^happy')
```